# Definition of Selmer group, latex

Tags: math-mode

```
$\text{Sel}^{\phi}(E/\Bbb{Q}) 
  = \{d\in \Bbb{Q}(S,2)\mid C_d(\Bbb{Q}_p)\neq \emptyset , \forall p\in S,
     C_d: dy^2=d^2-4Dx^4\}$
```

I want to express above set as the following.

[image]

But two conditions does not compile as above at this stage.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Sel}{Sel}

\begin{document}

\[
\Sel^{\phi}(E/\mathbb{Q})=
\left\{
  d\in \mathbb{Q}(S,2)
  \;\middle|\;
  \begin{aligned}
  & C_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)\neq \emptyset , \forall p\in S, \\
  & C_d: dy^2=d^2-4Dx^4
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

1. `\Bbb` has been deprecated for decades;
2. `\text{Sel}` isn't really good;
3. in order to *print* braces you need `\{` and `\}` (in this case the extensible ones).

[image]